# Get values which exist in one record but doesn't exist in another

Tags: sql

I have these table:

```
| NUMBER | NUMBER_LIST |     
| 520    | 1           |    
| 430    | 1           |    
| 870    | 1           |    
| 430    | 2           |
```

And I would like to get all NUMBERs which are exist in NUMBER_LIST = 1, but I wouldn't to get NUMBERs which are exist in NUMBER_LIST = 2. Finally I should get numbers 870 and 520 but I shouldn't get number 430 because this number exist in NUMBER_LIST = 2.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do that:

```
select NUMBER from TABLE
where NUMBER_LIST = 1
and NUMBER not in (select NUMBER from TABLE where NUMBER_LIST=2)
```

Or you could use a self-join instead of a subquery:

```
select NUMBER 
from TABLE t1
left join TABLE t2 on t1.NUMBER=t2.NUMBER and t2.NUMBER_LIST=2
where t1.NUMBER_LIST = 1
and t2.NUMBER is null
```

Comment: I used your first solution and MySQL return an error: "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)". Here is my request: "SELECT number, number_list FROM `numbers` WHERE number_list = 1 AND number_list NOT IN (SELECT number, number_list FROM `numbers` WHERE number_list = 2 AND number_list = 3);"

Comment: That doesn't look like my solution. It should be `and NUMBER not in (select NUMBER from TABLE where NUMBER_LIST=2)`

Comment: Sorry but it still doesn't work. Here you can see all numbers: http://s2.ifotos.pl/img/demopng_snqrnee.png and here is my request: "SELECT number FROM `numbers` WHERE number_list = 1 AND number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM `numbers` WHERE number_list = 2 AND number_list = 3)". This is result: http://s10.ifotos.pl/img/demopng_snqrneq.png. Why it return number 666555444 (list number 2 - ignore list) and number 509585475 (list number 3 - ignore list) ??

Comment: `SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE number_list = 2 AND number_list = 3` one row can not have number_list = 2 AND number_list = 3.. you should use OR `SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE number_list = 2 OR number_list = 3`  or better yet you can just use <> 1 `SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE number_list <> 1`

Comment: Why do you keep changing what I wrote? Copy and paste it. If your real question is different, then *ask that question*.

Comment: I edited only column's names and I added second list to ignore, that's all.

Comment: Yep, well, that broke the query. Read @JamieD77's comment to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select number from table1 group by number having count(number) = 1
```

for MSSQL

result:

```
| number |
|--------|
|    520 |
|    870 |
```